# Syntax error with select in select in vb to access SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I got a SQL statement where am selecting from an access database in vb but I get this error; "syntax error in query expression select sum(brought_qtty)" when I run my program. I imagine am doing the right thing but seems am not. How can I adjust this select? The code is below:

```
"select distinct(brought_price) as [Price], select sum(brought_qtty) as [Ordinary] from brought_coffee where " & _
"coffee_grade=O, select sum(brought_qtty) as [Premium] from brought_coffee where" & _
"coffee_grade=P, sum(brought_qtty) as [Total Qtty]" & _
", sum(brought_paid) as [paid],  " & _
"sum(brought_bal) as [Balance]" & _
"from brought_coffee, farmer where brought_date=#" & dtc.Text.Trim & "# and farmer_centre='" & cc.Text.Trim & _
"' and farmer.farmer_num=brought_coffee.farmer_num"
```

Comment: Use the query design window to create a query that works or at least gives you something close to what you want and post it here.

Comment: Thanks @Remou. Let me try that

Comment: **NEVER** use string concatenation to substitute in data from user controls like that! You're setting yourself up to get hacked.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third `select` in the query produce a syntax error... Replace `select sum(brought_qtty)` with just `sum(brought_qtty)`.

Comment: will that work. The problem is the inner select has more statements in the where clause

Comment: @ken, there is no inner select in that query... I just noticed now that you have more `where` clauses too... This is invalid syntax. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok @Radu. Let me just describe my table a bit. I have a column called "brought_qtty" which holds integer values while another called "coffee_grade" holds text values O or P. My main problem is around here where I want to select sum of brought_qtty to return three values in a row, overall sum, sum when coffee_grade is O and sum when coffee_grade is P. How can I do that?

Comment: @ken, using separate queries or a [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208962(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: separate queries are ok but I think they won't work for this situation because am filling the result in a datagridview. I don't know how to use union but let me find that out. Thank for your help